# Qt Creator: When I enable Shadow Builds, why do I get error related to missing files?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I added an image to resources, and displaying it worked fine. Then, I removed the file from resources in the Qt project, and I moved the file to a new images folder and re-added it to resources.

Now the project will only compile if "Shadow Build" option is un-checked in build settings.

If Shadow Build is enabled, I receive an error,

> "No rule to make target '../--project_name--/--image_name--', needed
>   by 'debug/qrc_qml.cpp'. Stop."

where `--project_name--` is the name of my project, etc.

This error doesn't make much sense, considering the file no longer exists at that location. What's going on here?

Comment: Have you tried to execute `qmake` step before build?

Comment: I ran qmake and it worked. Still baffled as to why Build or especially Rebuild All wouldn't run qmake, but thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to run qmake. This can be done from Build->run qmake. Qmake regenerates makefiles, which 'build' and 'build all' do not. The problem is that references to the file at its old location were not being removed by rebuilding. Credit to Andrii for pointing to answer in comment above.